# CommandTimeout in EF Core with MySql not working

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, timeout

I have below code a that runs a complex select query involving large dataset so my Api takes around 120s to send the response... I want a timeout where the query is cancelled in MySql after timeout is reached.

Below is code that runs the query

```
public async Task<GeoName> LoadById(int geonameId)
{
    return await this.dbContext.GeoNames
        .Include("Children.Child.AlternateNames")
        .Include(gn => gn.AlternateNames)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(g => g.Id == geonameId);    
}
```

I've tried to add in connection string and in code but unable to make it work. My request still completes in over 2 minutes.

`"maximumpoolsize=10;Pooling=True;default command timeout=30;"`

I also added Command timeout to DbContext

```
public LocaleInfoDbContext(DbContextOptions<LocaleInfoDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
    Database.SetCommandTimeout(30);
}
```

Finally I tried

```
services.AddDbContextPool<LocaleInfoDbContext>((options) =>
    {
        string mySqlConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("LocaleInfo");
        options.UseMySql(mySqlConnectionString, (options) =>
        {
            options.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 12), Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure.ServerType.MySql));
            options.CommandTimeout(30);
        });
        
    });
```

Need help here... I have select query that takes a long time to run and I will optimise and fix it but I want to make sure that no query runs beyond timeout... When there is high traffic, it creates too many connections and all start to queue up...

I also checked below but not sure how to use it, in fact if I add it to my connection string, I get an error. I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Version="3.1.1"

Comment: Try to add `AsSplitQuery()`, probably cartesian explosion of returned records.

Comment: yeah I know the issue with the query and it can be resolved... However I wish to understand how timeouts work and how I can terminate the query if timeout is breached

Comment: Probably here command executed in reasonable time but retrieving result is still in progress. Do you use `CancellationToken`?